# Is there a specific way of 'withdrawing' a question thats deemed off-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration

I commented on a question for a user to move their question from Stack Overflow to Android Stack Exchange. Is there an alternative way of withdrawing a question or moving it to a new Stack Exchange instead of deleting the question and re-posting elsewhere? can you 'move' the question?

Comment: Questions can be migrated to specific SE sites, that appear in the corresponding close reason.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is true, but only works for the 5 or so "auto-migration" paths that are defined.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I meant this handful (_"that appear in the corresponding close reason"_)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raise a custom flag asking a moderator to migrate it to the target site.

Now, migrations are only done for *good* content, so make sure your question would be high quality at the place you want to send it to. We don't want to move crap around.

Also, don't be surprised if it isn't acted on for a while, the moderators are very busy. My last migration flag took several days (up to a week) to be handled IIRC.

If it *is* crap, then just delete it. The only other "withdrawal" mechanism is disassociation, but there's no need to do that for junk.

Comment: very informative. Would the moderator have full decision on whether the content is high quality or not? or is it automatically done?

Comment: @BradleyWilson Its purely up to the moderator. Of course, users at the target site can reject the migration by closing it, but we don't like to see that happen.

Comment: I have had a migration flag pending for five days right now (still pending).  If *you* posted it, you're generally better off just deleting and reposting it yourself.